# RecyclerView.Adapter. Overridden method onCreateViewHolder argument always get zero in viewType argument

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make RecyclerView with multiple view types. Like in this topic: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-types).

I understand essential of this approach is method **getItemViewType(position: Int): Int{}**.

This **viewType** tells **onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)** which one of two holder to create.
In a test project everything works well.

But in this particular RecyclerView Adapter, method onCreateViewHolder always get **zero**. Even if I set viewType hard way like this override.

```
fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int { return 100 }
```

I'll be glad any clue. This is my code:

```
    class OrdersAdapter(val iAbsListFragment: IAbsListFragment,
                    val listItemsLD: LiveData<Result<List<Order>>>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OrderViewHolder {
        viewType
        return OrderViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.card_order, parent, false), iAbsListFragment
        )
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int { return 100 }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if (listItemsLD.value is Result.Success) {
            (listItemsLD.value as Result.Success<List<Order>>).data.size
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OrderViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (listItemsLD.value is Result.Success) {
            val order = (listItemsLD.value as Result.Success<List<Order>>).data[position]
            holder.bindTo(order)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not ask my why. **onCreateViewHolder** must return **RecyclerView.ViewHolder** but **not RecyclerView.ViewHolder implementation**, then viewType argument will get viewType from getItemViewType(position: Int)

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OrderViewHolder //wrong, viewType always zero

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OrderViewHolder //work well, viewType from "override fun getItemViewType"
```